# Opposite of notranslate class for translation services

Tags: html, google-translate

In HTML, you can direct translation services not to translate certain HTML elements by adding class="notranslate" to them ([source](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ie/2008/10/helping-you-break-language-barrier.html)).

Is there any method to create the opposite behavior? Such that you can mark the elements that *should* be translated, and only those will be?

Comment: From the link you have provided: <meta name="google" value="notranslate"> . Doesn't that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class `notranslate` on your body.
Then, use the same method with inner nodes using the class `translate`.

```
<body class="notranslate">
    <p class="translate">Will be translated</p>
    <p>Will not be translated</p>
</body>
```